# NFS connection timing out on EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nfs, amazon-eks

I have an NFS helm chart. It is one of the charts for an application that has 5 more sub-charts. 2 of the charts have a shared storage which I am using NFS. In GCP when I provide NFS service name in the PV it works.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: {{ include "nfs.name" . }}
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: {{ .Values.persistence.nfsVolumes.size }}
  accessModes:
    - {{ .Values.persistence.nfsVolumes.accessModes }}
  mountOptions:
    - nfsvers=4.1
  nfs:
    server: nfs.default.svc.cluster.local # nfs is from svc {{ include "nfs.name" .}}
    path: "/opt/shared-shibboleth-idp"
```

But the same doesn't work on AWS EKS. The error there - on AWS EKS - is connection timeout so it can't mount the volume.
When I change the server to

`server: a4eab2d4aef2311e9a2880227e884517-1524131093.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com` .

I get connection timed out.

All the mounts are okay since it works well with GCP. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you are testing this deployment with nfs server on two separate clusters? Or you are trying to use nfs from one cluster on another cluster?

Comment: The NFS server and the other microservices are on the same cluster.

Comment: You wrote that you get connection timeout on EKS with both `nfs.default.svc.cluster.local` and `a4eab2d4aef2311e9a2880227e884517-1524131093.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com` is that correct? Or you meant to say that the second one is working?

Comment: `You wrote that you get connection timeout on EKS with both nfs.default.svc.cluster.local and a4eab2d4aef2311e9a2880227e884517-1524131093.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com` that is correct @Crou

Comment: Which helm chars are you using? Are the pods working correctly, can you post logs? Have you exposed the share?